# What is the difference between `Ref: logicalName` and `!Ref logicalName` in AWS Cloudformation templates in YAML?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What is the difference between `Ref:` and `!Ref` in AWS Cloudformation templates in YAML?

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html), `Ref: logicalName` is "syntax for the full function name" and `!Ref logicalName` is "syntax for the short form". Is there functionally a difference between the full function name and short form. Can I just use either or?

Answer (score 8):

You can use either. It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: But why? Doesn't 'syntactic sugar' usually reduce the amount of text/code you have to write? This just swaps one character for another/change position.

Comment: `Ref:` is the only form supported by JSON formatted cloudformation (the only format supported at launch). YAML supports tags which you can use shorthand with the exclamation point e.g. `!Ref`.

Comment: !Ref might not shorter, but others like !GetAtt and !Join are much easier to read than the alternative.

Comment: Not really, `!Ref` causes error when used here `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup >> TargetGroupARNs: - Ref...` or here `AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate >> SecurityGroups: - Ref...` and it should be `Ref`

Answer (score 3):

Both syntaxes work exactly the same, as they are *different ways* of calling the *same function*.

Note that the syntax of the full-function name requires an object to be created:

```
- !Ref myPhysicalId
- Ref: myPhisicalId
```

In a more complex example:

Long syntax is used as a dictionary:

```
    ApiGatewayResourceFavicon:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: favicon.ico
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
```

Short syntax is used in the same line, hence the "short" part of the name:

```
    ApiGatewayResourceFavicon:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: favicon.ico
        RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi << Note Ref is used as a string
```