Creating Glue table with serverless.yaml gives 'Table name must not contain uppercase characters' error even if name is in lower case
I am trying to create a AWS Glue Database and Table using Serverless framework. Here is the yaml code that I have been using to test:
org: testorg
service: TestAthenaServerless

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    ReportsBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: test-bucket
    TestDatabase:
      Type: AWS::Glue::Database
      Properties:
        DatabaseInput:
          Name: school_db
          Description: testing athena serverless 
        CatalogId: Ref AWS::AccountId
    StudentTable: 
      Type: AWS::Glue::Table
      Properties:
        DatabaseName: Ref TestDatabase
        CatalogId: Ref AWS::AccountId
        TableInput:
          Name: student_table
          Description: Serverless test table
          TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
          StorageDescriptor: 
            Columns:
            - {Name: student_name, Type: string}
            - {Name: student_id, Type: string}
            - {Name: roll_no, Type: string}
            - {Name: gender, Type: string}
            Location: s3://test-bucket/students
          Parameters: {}

As can be seen above, the table name is student_table that is all lower case. But deploying fails with error:
✖ An error occurred: StudentTable - Table name [ student_table ] must not contain uppercase characters.
ServerlessError2: An error occurred: StudentTable - Table name [ student_table ] must not contain uppercase characters.

Can someone point me to where I am going wrong?
I tried changing the table name to a single word studenttable, using hyphen instead of underscore etc but end up with same error.

Have you tried changing the cloud formation template such as     studenttable:  # Changed logical ID to lowercase
Type: AWS::Glue::Table
Properties:
DatabaseName: Ref TestDatabase
CatalogId: Ref AWS::AccountId
TableInput:
Name: student_table
Description: Serverless test table
TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE to see if that's the issue?

Thanks Jeff. Same issue: An error occurred: studenttable - Table name [ student_table ] must not contain uppercase characters.

You must change your Ref ... references for !Ref .... that will fix it.

Thank you so much. This worked! Can you add a bit more detail on the difference between just using Ref and !Ref

You got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050242/what-is-the-difference-between-ref-logicalname-and-ref-logicalname-in-aws
